# Stop webpack adding script tag at the bottom of the file

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am using webpack to generate a html file using HtmlWebpackPlugin - I would like all code injected instead of referencing any exdternal javascript files.

Webpack seems to me inluding main.js at the bottom on the html document, is there a way to stop this happening?

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

My webpack config looks like this

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require("fs");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './Resources/TestExport/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Resources')
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'TestExport.html',
            template: './Resources/TestExport/SecureExportTemplate.html',
            inject: true,
            jquery: fs.readFileSync('./Resources/TestExport/js/jquery.js', 'utf8'),
            testExport: require("@babel/core").transformSync(fs.readFileSync('./Resources/TestExport/js/testExport.js', 'utf8'), {
                "presets": [["@babel/preset-env"]]
            }).code,
            style: fs.readFileSync('./Resources/TestExport/css/style.css', 'utf8'),
            minify: {
                html5: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributese: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: If you have already achieved injecting of data directly, just looking to remove inclusion of js file, I think `inject: false,` can do that.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after - thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have already achieved injecting of data directly

and just looking to remove inclusion of js file, `inject: false,` can do that.